# Getting the global id if we had the global size only and the local id?

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

What is the global id if we had a 2D index space, with work groups of size (14,30). If a particular execution of the kernel in workgroup (2,3) has

```
get_local_id(0) = 5 and get_local_id(1) = 7
```

What would be for get_global_id(0) and get_global_id(1) ? I actually do not have the local size!

How can we calculate?

Does is it equal to

```
get_global_id(0) = 5*2 = 10

get_global_id(1) = 3*7 = 21
```

Comment: I understand that you have already the knowledge of using the kernel calls for this, don't you? So you are only asking for the manual method. Because all the parameters can be directly queried to the OpenCL API, size, id, dimensions, group id, there is no need to do it manually. https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/workItemFunctions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the local size. And thankfully you can get it by calling get_local_size. It will always return a valid value.

It goes like this assuming no offset:

```
get_global_id(0) = get_local_id(0)+get_local_size(0)*get_group_id(0)
```

Remember that even if you call your kernel with NULL as the local size the implementation will make something up so that you will always get valid values.

Comment: +1 for your answer.. What if we were to calculate without any coding?.. what would be the get_local_size value from the information given above?

Comment: "with work groups of size (14,30)". I'm assuming this is what get_local_size would return and workgroup(2,3) refers to the group_id. That would mean the global_id(0) would be 5 + 14*2 = 33.